# optimal algorithm for finding unique divisors

Tags: algorithm

I was just thinking of a problem which does not seem to be much hard but when we think of doing it optimally, it becomes quite a good problem. The problem is- We have been given a list(array) of numbers and a number N. We have to find the all the divisors of N which doesn't divide any number belonging to the list. I have solved it with a brute force and a little efficient  approach(but not the best one). So, I am looking for an approach which could be the best in solving this kind of problem.Everything is in terms of integer(no floating points). Every idea is appreciated.

My approach to this is that I first find all the divisors of the number N(without any overhead).Then, I sort the list and the divisors in reverse order(separately). Now, for each divisor D, I check if it divides any number in the list(starting from the highest element upto an element which is >= the divisor D). If it divides, then all divisors of D must also divide. Then I remove those elements from the list of divisors which are also the divisors of D(can be thought of as removing the intersection). So, ultimately the left array of divisors is the required array(according to my approach). If someone can point any fault or any lack of efficiency in my approach, it is appreciated. The max value which can be present in the list is 10^18.

My attempt so far in PHP:

```
while($div=each($divisors))
{
$i=0;
$divisor=$div['key'];
//echo "divisor is $divisor\n";
while((int)$unfriendly[$i]>=$divisor)
{//echo "aya\n";
    if(!((int)bcmod($unfriendly[$i],$divisor)))
    {//echo "ayeea\n";
        $divisors_of_divisor=divisors_of_a_number($divisor);
        //print_r($divisors_of_divisor);
        //print_r($divisors);
        foreach($divisors_of_divisor as $d)
        unset($divisors[$d]);
        //print_r($divisors);
        break;
    }
    ++$i;
}
 }
echo sizeof($divisors);
function divisors_of_a_number($n)//returns all the divisors of a number in an unsorted array
{
$i=1;
$s=sqrt($n);
while($i<=$s)
{
if(!($n%$i))
{
    $a[]=$i;
    if($i!=$s)
    $a[]=$n/$i;
}
++$i;
}
return $a;
}
function divisors_of_a_number_as_keys_of_array($n)//returns all the divisors of a number in an unsorted array as keys
{
$i=1;
$s=sqrt($n);
while($i<=$s)
{
if(!($n%$i))
{
    $a[$i]=1;
    //if($i!=$s)
    $a[$n/$i]=1;
}
++$i;
}
return $a;
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your effort here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious optimization is the following - do [sieve of eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to fatorize all numbers up to a value you know is higher then any single one in the list you are given. Now you can iterate over all the factors of a given number from that list.

What you do next is: for each number from the list and each of its prime factors p you should divide N by p until it is divisible by it. After you do that the divisors you are looking for are all divisors of the remaining number.

Hope this helps.