# optimal algorithm for particular divisors

Tags: php, algorithm

**Not a duplicate of-**
[optimal algorithm for finding unique divisors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061108/optimal-algorithm-for-finding-unique-divisors)

I came across this problem. I am not able to find an optimal algorithm.

**The problem is :**

Given a list `L` of natural numbers(number can be really large) and a number `N`, what's the optimal algorithm to determine the number of divisors of `N` which doesn't not divide any of the numbers present in the list `L`. Numbers in the list can be repetitive ie, one number can occur more than once.

**Observation:**

Divisors of some divisor `d` of `N` are also divisors of `N`.

**MY approach was :**

1. Find the divisors of `N`.
2. Sort L in reverse order(largest element being 1st element).
3. foreach divisor `d` of `N`, I check whether it divides any element in the list or not.(stop when you come to check for an element less than `d` in the list, as the list is sorted)
4. If `d` divides some number in the list `L`, then I don't check for any divisor of `d`, that is, I skip this checking.
5. Ultimately, left divisors which were neither divided any number in the list nor skipped are counted. This count is the final answer.

But this algorithm is not optimal for this problem.

Any ideas for a better algorithm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [optimal algorithm for finding unique divisors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061108/optimal-algorithm-for-finding-unique-divisors)

Comment: @amit No it is not. Please don't say it on my every question. I ask question after searching a lot. Read the question statements clearly first.

Comment: I am sorry if I am mistaken, I'm only a human, but if I am - you should **link** to your previous question [as related], and mention **what have you done since**, and especially **emphasize the differences** between this question and the last.

Comment: @amit If you read the question, you will get the differences in 1 go. This happens because I can't create new tags, so my old tags match the tags for this problem. So everyone gets this as 1st option in related problems column.

Comment: @I have edited it the way you said.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look into is : **[co-primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime)** (or **relatively primes**)

> In number theory, a branch of mathematics, two integers a and b are
>   said to be coprime (also spelled co-prime) or relatively prime if the
>   only positive integer that evenly divides both of them is 1.

**So to "transcode" your problem :**

You basically want to find the Number of coprimes of `N` from the `L` list.

**When `a` and `b` are co-primes?**

[image]

> If two numbers are relatively prime then their greatest common divisor (GCD)
>   is 1

**Example code (for GCD) in PHP :**

```
<?php
$gcd = gmp_gcd("12", "21");
echo gmp_strval($gcd) . "\n";
?>
```

**Simply put :**

- `$count = 0`
- Foreach element `e` in list `L` : calculate the `GCD(e,N)`
- Is their GCD=1? If yes, they are coprime (so `N` and `e` have no common divisors). Count it up. `$count++`

And that's all there is to it.

Comment: That sounds new but I am not able to think that what do I do after finding coprimes of N from list L? Please state some more detail.

Comment: I understood the meaning of coprimes and I have read them before also. But, what I am not getting is how is finding the coprimes exactly going to help. Please explain in some more detailed words.

Comment: @user1320006 I've just updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Actually, you got the problem wrong. I want the number of divisors of N which doesn't divide any of the numbers present in the list.

Comment: @user1320006 well, first of all 12 and 21 are NOT coprime. Let me think about it...

Comment: I wrote that by mistake. I am waiting. Thanks.

Comment: @user1320006 Actually, I still think I'm 100% right. If let's say `e` (an element from your List) and `N` are co-primes, that means they have NO COMMON DIVISORS. So, let's say `N`'s divisors are : `a`,`b`,`c`. This means that `a`,`b`,`c` DO NOT DIVIDE `e` (they have no common divisors, right?). So, I insist that : simply by taking all elements (let's say `e`) from your list (perhaps with some sorting, first? I'm not sure), calculating the GCD of `e` and `N` and counting only thoses case where GCD=1, you'll get **exactly** what you want.

Comment: @user1320006 Am I getting "The number of L's elements for which no N's divisors divide them"? Hmmm... perhaps. I'm confused myself too...

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Just finding the co primes wouldn't have done and that's what I was trying to point out. I will try this and do let you know if it works.

Comment: Yes, you were getting them before. But what you suggested at last seems to work fine. Thanks.

Comment: @user1320006 Well, honestly I'm not 100% sure if I'm right. However, since I've been involved a lot with number theory -related calculations in the past, and that thing like "shouted" to me that it needed a "coprime" approach, please do give it a try... (or at least to a variant of it). Good luck! ;-)

Comment: I will try to. Thanks a lot for your time. By the way, I think this is a good problem, so why has it been rated -2? I am beginner sO I don't have chatting privileges.That's why I am asking here.

Comment: @user1320006 You're welcome, my friend! I think it's an intriguing problem too; and I sure am too excited to get my hands dirty every time something interesting pops up. (btw, why do you want to do something like that? I was wondering...) Now, as for the downvotes, while StackOverflow is a GREAT community, it's not so unlikely that someone downvotes simply for the sake of it, or because he may consider a question duplicate or off-topic  or whatever (when it's actually not). Don't bother... :-)

Comment: @user1320006 Yet another question : why do you want to implement this in PHP? Since it's seemingly a calculation-intense problem, I would definitely go in a more compiler-friendly approach. What about C/C++, for example? (also I suspect you could also make use of the GMP (bignum library) there, since you'll most likely have to deal with ultra-big numbers at some point or the other + there are built-in functions for most integer operations (and for GCD as well...))

Comment: @user1320006 Now, again as for the downvotes : I would definitely have UPvoted your question myself (since it's one of those questions I'm particularly interested in), but unfortunately I've no votes left for today (StackOverflow allows 40 votes max per day), so... by tomorrow...

Comment: oh! Thanks. Actually I came across this problem. I mostly solve problems in PHP. I know C/C++ but I feel comfortable with PHP. I am using BC modules like bcdiv, bcmod etc. for heavy calculations.

Answer (score 0):

First, factorize n and represent it in the following way: p1:k1, p2:k2,..., pm:km such that p1,p2,... are all primes and n=p1^k1 * p2^k2 ....

Now, iterate over r1, r2, r3,..., rm such that r1<=k1, r2<=k2, ..., rm<=km and check if p1^r1*p2^r2...*pm^rm divides any number in L. If not increment count by 1.

Optimization: Pick a value for r1. See if p1^r1 divides any number in L. If yes, then pick a number for r2 and so on. If p1^r1 does not divide any number in L, then increment count by (k2+1)*(k3+1)*..*(km+1).

Example N=72, L=[4, 5, 9, 12, 15, 20]:
Writing N as a primal product: 2:3, 3:2 (2^3*3*2 = 72).

```
p1=2, p2=3, k1=3, k2=2
count=0
r1=0:
    r2=0:
        Divides 4
r1=0:
    r2=1:
        Divides 9
r1=0:
    r2=2:
        Divides 9
r1=1:
    r2=0:
        Divides 4
r1=1:
    r2=1:
        Divides 12
r1=1:
    r2=2:
        L not divisible by 18. Count+=1 = 1
r1=2:
    r2=0:
        Divides 4
r1=2:
    r2=1:
        Divides 12
r1=2:
    r2=2:
        L not divisible by 36. Count+=1 = 2
r1=3:
    r2=0:
        L not divisible by 8. Count+=(k2+1) +=(2+1) = 5
```

Comment: Could you please present a working example? Its hard to understand in this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. By the way, I think this is a good problem, so why has it been rated -2? I am beginner sO I don't have chatting privileges.That's why I am asking here.

Comment: @user1320006 Not sure since I was not the one downvoted. Probably because the same exact question was asked earlier (see the link posted by amit)

Comment: I am sorry to say, but even after your this hard effort, it is unable to understand your algorithm this way. You also have some mistakes in writing which become confusion. And one thing, have you mistakenly written r1 as rb1? if not, what does rb1 signify? and how is it different from r1?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Divisors {
  public $factor = array();

  public function __construct($num) {
    $this->num = $num;
  }

  // count number of divisors of a number
  public function countDivisors() {
    if ($this->num == 1) return 1;

    $this->_primefactors();

    $array_primes = array_count_values($this->factor);
    $divisors = 1;
    foreach($array_primes as $power) {
      $divisors *= ++$power;
    }
    return $divisors;
  }

  // prime factors decomposer
  private function _primefactors() {
    $this->factor = array();
    $run = true;
    while($run && @$this->factor[0] != $this->num) {
      $run = $this->_getFactors();
    }
  }

  // get all factors of the number
  private function _getFactors() {
    if($this->num == 1) {
      return ;
    }
    $root = ceil(sqrt($this->num)) + 1;
    $i = 2;
    while($i <= $root) {
      if($this->num % $i == 0) {
        $this->factor[] = $i;
        $this->num = $this->num / $i;
        return true;
      }
      $i++;
    }
    $this->factor[] = $this->num;
    return false;
  }
} // our class ends here

    $example = new Divisors(4567893421);
    print $example->countDivisors();
?>
```

Comment: does it count the exact number of divisors for a given number? Or it counts what I asked for?